# Why the code ins't reaching the IFTTT webhooks server?

Tags: python, webhooks

I'm really a babe in coding, but created this script for running random quotes and wanted to transfer this to spreadhsheets. Unfortunately the Google API ins't working, and for now nothing the I could Search solved this. So anyway, here goes the problem:

I trying to reach a webserver created with WebHooks in IFTTT, but for somehow I can't do it and nether find why.
Here goes the code:

```
import random
import time
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)




adv1 = (" EXCESSIVAMENTE", " EXAGERADAMENTE",  " IMENSAMENTE", " GRANDEMENTE",  " ASSUSTADORAMENTE", " INDEFINIDAMENTE", " EXTRAORDINARIAMENTE", " EM GRANDE QUANTIDADE", " EM IMENSA QUANTIDADE"," EM EXCESSIVA QUANTIDADE", " AMPLAMENTE")

adv2 = ("MUITO", "MUITÍSSIMO", "IMENSO", "BASTANTE", "GRANDE", "IMENSO", "ENORME", "DESMEDIDO", "COLOSSAL", "GIGANTESCO","EXCEPCIONAL", "ATÍPICO", "INCOMUM", "INESPERADO", "INUSITADO", "RARO", "EXTRAORDINÁRIO", "DEMAIS", "ABUNDANTE")

substdinheiro = ("DINHEIRO", "FORTUNA", "CAPITAL", "RIQUEZA", "RECURSOS")

subst2online = (" ONLINE", " CONECTADO NA INTERNET", " COM SEU CELULAR", " COM SEU COMPUTADOR", " COM SEU CELULAR E COMPUTADOR", " USANDO SEU CELULAR", " USANDO SEU COMPUTADOR", " USANDO A INTERNET", " USANDO AS REDES SOCIAIS")

hashtags = ("#DINHEIRO","#SUCESSO", "#EMPREENDEDORISMO", "#MARKETINGDIGITAL", "#RENDAEXTRA", "#EMPREENDER", "#INVESTIMENTO", "#MARKETING", "#MOTIVAÇAO", "#FOCO", "#INVESTIMENTOS", "#LIBERDADEFINANCEIRA", "#BRASIL", "#GANHARDINHEIRO", "#EMPREENDEDOR", "#NEGOCIOS", "#DINHEIRONOBOLSO", "#VENDAS", "#MONEY", "#TRABALHO", "#BOLSADEVALORES", "#DINHEIROONLINE","#HOTMART", "#ECONOMIA", "#DINHEIROEXTRA")
verbo = ("OBTENHA ", "CONSIGA ", "ALCANCE ", "RECEBA ", "GANHE ", "LUCRE ", "RETIRE ", "FAÇA ", "ARRECADE ", "CRIE ", "EXTRAIA ", "SAQUE ", "TENHA ")


def test(first):
    while True:
        report = {}
        report['value1'] = first
        requests.post("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/python/with/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-zvsIXCgx3RVj", data=report)
        return ""




while True:

    print(random.choice(verbo), random.choice(substdinheiro), random.choice(adv1), random.choice(subst2online),"!", sep='')
    a=input()
    test(a)



    time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you done any debugging? There's no way for us to run this, right?

Comment: what is the error info？

Comment: what do you want to get from this request,  why not process it;s response ?

Answer (score 1):

you never called the test method

Comment: edited, called the def in the end but still can't reach the server...